# Usage of v-for for looping through an array of objects in order to output a specific field's value

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I have two objects/model:

```
export class AObject {
  public anumber: string;
}


export class BObject {
  public aObject: AObject[];
}
```

Inside my template, I would like to loop through an array of `AObject[]` and for each of them output the value for the property `anumber`. I have attempted at the following, but it is not working:

```
           <div class="fields fields-flex">
              <div class="field">
                <label>{{ $t('myLabel.aLabel') }}</label>
                <span v-for="(aObject) in aObjects" 
                  :key="aObject.number"> 
                  {{bObject.aObjects.number}}"</span>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Can you help?

Thanks!

Comment: Try {{ aObject.anumber }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `aObject[]` as an array then your loop should look like

```
<span v-for="aObjectInstance in aObject" 
 :key="aObjectInstance.anumber"> 
</span>
```

`aObject` is the name of the array, therefore `aObject` should be after `in`.

Also, you should have `v-for` for going through all the `BObject.aObject`, you can't reference it like `{{bObject.aObjects.number}}"` because you don't have `aObjects` on `BObject` but `aObject` *.

So that should look like:

```
<span v-for="aObject in BObject.aObject" 
 :key="aObject.anumber">
 {{aObject.number}}"
</span>
```

I hope this helps.